# Navigation between page windows phone Silverlight 8.0, MVVM model

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm, navigation

I started a project using MVVM model. My app start on the MainPage class. I want to switch to another page that I created (I know we can do it in the default seeting but i prefer to do it by code, to be able to switch again later). So my first question how should I creat my page ? The "solution" for me is to navigate to my Page(login) then set the datacontext of my Page to my viewmodel.

I created some viewcontroller inside my page and I also wanted to know if the datacontext of my page is going to be automaticaly set my viewcontrollers.

```
public class Login : MyNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Client client_ { get; set; }

    private ICommand inscription;

    public ICommand Inscription
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.inscription == null)
                this.inscription = new MyCommand(() => this.client_.Connection(this.client_.clientInfo_));

            return this.inscription;
        }
    }

    public Login()
    {
        client_ = new Client();
    }
```

This is my ViewModel

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Views:Identify Name="identify" Grid.Row="1"></Views:Identify>
    <Views:Logo Grid.Row="0"></Views:Logo>
    <Views:Register Grid.Row="2"></Views:Register>
</Grid>
```

This is my page that i want to set the datacontext to my login class.

And this is my MainPage

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Login/Login.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Without seeing the code you created for your viewcontroller, how can we answer how it'll behave?

Comment: Ok i figure out to set the datacontext of my page.